# How to make angled borders for tables.

Tags: html, css

I've searched high and low and found some stuff, but nothing pertaining to what I need exactly.

I need this:[image: what I need]

And I currently have this:
[image: what I have]

My question is how to make the first right side border an angle as shown via CSS.

Right now, I am making this as a table (I know, tables are so 2000's).

```html
<table class="issue-finder">
  <tr>
    <td class="first-child"><a href="#">Issue<br>Finder</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">P-12<br>Education</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Higher<br>Education</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Workforce<br>Outcomes</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Health &amp; Human<br>Services</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And CSS is:

```css
.issue-finder {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #c2db73;
}
.issue-finder td.first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}
.issue-finder td {
    width: 15%;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.issue-finder a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Should I be doing this as a list like some of the examples I saw on SO or is a table fine?  If a table is fine, how would I go about coding it?  Thanks Guys!

Comment: I would not be using a table for this...too complex/

Comment: From a semantic point of view, that content doesn't belong in a table (at least add `role="presentation"`) but rather belongs in an unordered list. From a practical point of view, you'll probably have an easier time styling a list than a table.

Comment: Found something to only use CSS-HTML. See my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add a class to your first td and in this class set `background-image` to your custom arrow. Like:

```
.issue-finder td.first-child {
    border-right: 0px;
    /*your custom image*/
    background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/76/Fl%C3%A8che_directionnelle.png/800px-Fl%C3%A8che_directionnelle.png);
    width: 20%; /*if you want it to be taller*/
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdminXVII/94rsztj6/)**

**UPDATE**

Found a cool website to make what you want with only CSS-HTML (no images):

http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: Gotta accept this as an answer as adminXVII got it closest.

Comment: Thanks adminXVII, looks like that will work.  I will try it later.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
width: 250px;
height: 150px;
background-image: url('http://rgartists.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/icon-ios7-arrow-right-128.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 250px 150px;
```

Uploaded a sample JSFiddle example, similar to yours. Its here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gHYsh/529/

Best of luck.

Comment: I see what you guys are doing with an image, and its very clever.  But I feel like there should be an easier way.  Hmm, I may just have to hack it with an image.  Thx all for your help.  If anyone has a better suggestion, Im all ears.  For now, looks like an img hack.  :)